# Why can I not retrieve the value of a link?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="search_item" style="display: block;">
    <li><a href="#">test one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

code:

```
$('.search_list li a').click(function(){
    var test = $(this).text();
    alert('test');
    return false;
})
```

When I click the link, why does it not alert the value?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, your selector appears to be wrong. The `ul` has a class name of "search_item", but you're selecting `.search_list`.

Secondly, you only alert a string literal. You need to remove the quotes to reference the variable you declared on the previous line:

```
$('.search_item li a').click(function (){
    //     ^-------Wrong selector!
    var test = $(this).text();
    alert(test);
    //    ^--^-----No quotes!
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Adding the demo for your cause `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/5sRQ9/ ! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Why not much simpler here: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wLhgY/1/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var test = $(this).text();
        alert(test);
        return false;

    });
});​
```

Comment: It's unlikely that the OP will want to bind that event handler to every `a` element on the page.

Comment: @JamesAllardice I saw your Post ++ `:)` and you covered most of the point then I thought; hmmmm OP what are you thinking! and then wacked in this simpler version. `:)` otherwise this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5sRQ9/

Answer (score 1):

`alert(test)`, not `alert('test')`

Answer (score 1):

man where is the `.search_list` class you define `class="search_item"` above!

and also your alert should be `alert(test);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.search_item li a').click(
function(){
   var test = $(this).text();
   alert(test);
    return false;
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.search_item li a').click(
function(){
    var test = $(this).text();
   alert(test);
  return false;    
});
```